# Running .NET .exe in Azure Data Factory

Tags: deployment, azure-data-factory

I have an `.exe` (console application) file written in C# , which I want to run using Azure Data Factory.

What are the steps I need to do to achieve this?

I know that for `.dll` files we have options to run them in azure, but what about `.exe` files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Stop trying to put a square peg in a round hole. It will have to be wrapped up as an ADF custom activity.

You need to inherit from the ADF base class and call the IDictionary execute method.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Models;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataFactories.Runtime;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1 : IDotNetActivity
    {
        public IDictionary string, string Execute(
                IEnumerable linkedServices,
                IEnumerable datasets,
                Activity activity,
                IActivityLogger logger)
        {
            logger.Write("Start");

            //Get extended properties
            DotNetActivity dotNetActivityPipeline = (DotNetActivity)activity.TypeProperties;

            string sliceStartString = dotNetActivityPipeline.ExtendedProperties["SliceStart"];

            //Get linked service details
            Dataset inputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset = dataset.Name == activity.Inputs.Single().Name);
            Dataset outputDataset = datasets.Single(dataset = dataset.Name == activity.Outputs.Single().Name);

            /*
                DO STUFF
            */

            logger.Write("End");

            return new Dictionary string, string();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://www.purplefrogsystems.com/paul/2016/11/creating-azure-data-factory-custom-activities/

Whatever methods you have in the console app just rewrite them as a class that can be instantiated by the Azure Batch Service compute pool, which is where ADF passed the compiled to.

This is how ADF does it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replay i run this with hinsight but it's faill

Answer (score 1):

Try function app where you can write same C# code and call the app from ADF as a HTTP call

Answer (score 0):

As Paul Andrew has pointed out, you need to use the custom activities SPI as described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities. You have three options:

- Change your project into a class library
- If you need the executable for some other purpose, refactor your solution into three separate projects: a class library containing the common logic, an executable project, and a data factory custom activity
- If you cannot change the code for some reason, you can create an activity that calls the .exe directly. A sample is provided at
  https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/master/Samples/RunRScriptUsingADFSample/InvokeRScript.cs

Comment: Thanks for replay,

Comment: Thanks for replay, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-use-custom-activities is now working, when i put my cube processing code it's fail with following message                                                      Unknown error in module: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ConnectionException: The connection string is not valid. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace